# Is there a way to set a dark background for StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering if there's a way to make the background for StackOverflow dark? I looked around in my profile area and what not but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to change the background color so it's easier on the eyes?

Comment: is there such a thing?

Comment: I only found something for SuperUser: http://stackapps.com/questions/3724/super-user-dark-theme

Comment: I made a Stack Overflow Dark Theme userscript: https://stackapps.com/questions/8053/stack-overflow-dark-theme